# React rendering test with role, testid and classname

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test react rendering. As I known, There is several method to find elements that I defined.

1. role
2. test id
3. class name
4. query selector

When should I define 'role' or 'test id' instance of class name, and What is differnce between role and test id?

Comment: What testing library are you using? It should cover how to target elements in the rendered DOM for testing.

Comment: I'm using this as test library. https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro

Comment: Updated answer to be more specific to react-testing-library. It's what I suspected you were using but didn't want to make any assumptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What is difference between role and test id?**

A `role` is a html attribute used in accessibility and semantic html structures.

[WAI-ARIA Roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles)

`test-id` are special id's used to hook onto a specific DOM node for testing. They are typically a [`data-X`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute, i.e. `data-testid="test"`, but could also be plain `id` attributes for some testing libraries.

You should primarily use roles as part of your applications accessibility strategy, not for testing.

**When should I define 'role' or 'test id' instance of class name?**

`react-testing-library` query [cheatsheet](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#queries)
[What Query Should I Use?](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query)

> Based on the Guiding Principles, your test should resemble how users interact with your code (component, page, etc.) as much as possible. With this in mind, we recommend this order of priority:
>
> 1. Queries accessible to everyone (label/placeholder text, aria role, text, and display values)
> 2. Semantic Queries (HTML5 and ARIA compliant selectors)
> 3. Test IDs
>      Manual queries on the container (`container.querySelector`)